# Elasticsearch 5.x Get API issues refresh. If so, is Get a high-cost operation in fact?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 2.3, and I know that Get API is realtime, i.e. the API retrieves the very recent document regardless of refresh_interval. This operation is totally independent of refresh.

While reading the ES 5.x documentation, I found the following:

> By default, the get API is realtime, and is not affected by the
>   refresh rate of the index (when data will become visible for search).
>   **If a document has been updated but is not yet refreshed, the get API
>   will issue a refresh call in-place to make the document visible. This
>   will also make other documents changed since the last refresh visible.**
>   In order to disable realtime GET, one can set the realtime parameter
>   to false.

I tested and confirmed that this isn't the case on ES 2.3 environment; Get API does not refresh the index although it certainly gets the updated document.

Does this mean that Get API in ES 5.x actually is a very high-cost operation, because so is refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change will only affect you, if you have an update and GET the document by ID before it has been refreshed. Is this a common scenario in your use case? Then you might want to disable `realtime`, but the assumption in general is that you should not run into that situation frequently.

This has been discussed on the PR of the change (and explains why the change has been made), so you should find that discussion helpful: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/20102

Overall, the GET API in ES 5.x could be more costly, but it will depend on your actual use case.